# Update query isn't updating the database?

Tags: java, sql

I have an "addAppointment" and a "updateAppointment" method that both use the same parameters.

```
public static void addAppointment(String title, String description, String location, String type, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, int customerID, int userID, int contactID) 
{

try { String sqlAddAppt = "INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, ?)";  
      PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlAddAppt);
      ps.setString(1, title);
      ps.setString(2, description); 
      ps.setString(3, location);  
      ps.setString(4, type);  
      ps.setTimestamp(5, Timestamp.valueOf(start)); 
      ps.setTimestamp(6, Timestamp.valueOf(end));  
      ps.setInt(7, customerID);    
      ps.setInt(8, userID);  
      ps.setInt(9, contactID);  
      ps.execute();   
 } 
catch (SQLException e) {       
 e.printStackTrace();    }}


public static void updateAppointment(String title, String description, String location, String type, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, int customerID, int userID, int contactID) {
try { 
   String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE appointments SET Title=?, Description=?, Location=?, Type=?, Start=?, End=?, Customer_ID=?, User_ID=?, Contact_ID=? WHERE Appointment_ID = ?;";
    PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
    ps.setString(1, title); 
    ps.setString(2, description);  
    ps.setString(3, location); 
    ps.setString(4, type); 
    ps.setTimestamp(5, Timestamp.valueOf(start)); 
    ps.setTimestamp(6, Timestamp.valueOf(end)); 
    ps.setInt(7, customerID); 
    ps.setInt(8, userID);  
    ps.setInt(9, contactID);  
    ps.execute(); } catch (SQLException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();    }}
```

I'm calling the methods the same way using :

```
DBAppointments.updateAppointment(title, description, location, type, startTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime(), endTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime(), customerID.getCustomerID(), userID.getUserID(), contact.getContactID());

DBAppointments.addAppointment(title, description, location, type, startTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime(), endTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime(), customerID.getCustomerID(), userID.getUserID(), contact.getContactID());
```

The "addAppointment" works perfectly and will Insert correctly but when I try to use the update method, it doesn't return any errors but it also does not update the database.  Any ideas?

Comment: What was processing when you called updateAppointment? Did it run exceucte()?

Comment: It seems that Appointment_ID not be set

Comment: Check if the transaction is commited explicitly or implicitly. Also, it makes sense to enable DEBUG and SQL query logging with parameter value shown. This will help diagnose the problem further. Also, you can read the DB logs and see what the DB sees

Comment: @HanhNguyen Thank you for the answer!  I pull the information from an appointment already in the database as variable "selectedAppointment".  I set it using "selectedAppointment.getAppointmentID" instead of "appointmentIDText" and now it updates correctly.  Thank you for the nudge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hibernate and JDBC which is a cleaner way to perform CRUD operations on your DB. It might be quite a different approach if you haven't seen it before however, I suggest you get familiar with this approach because it's a standard way to perform DB operation currently.

Start by defining your Entity and an interface then add a controller to perform your operations

```
@Entity('TableName')
public class Person {
 @Column('table_column_name')
 String title;

 @Column('table_column_name')
 String description;

 @Column('table_column_name')
 String location;

 @Column('table_column_name')
 String type; 

 @Column('table_column_name')
 LocalDateTime start; 

 @Column('table_column_name')
 LocalDateTime end; 

 @Column('table_column_name')
 int customerID; 

 @Column('table_column_name')
 int userID; 

 @Column('table_column_name')
 int contactID;
}

This person class is basically the column headings of your table in your 
database
```

You will create an interface which will house the DB operations

```
    public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
      /*This will contain all the database operations you want to perform. By 
       default, it contains the CRUD operations and if you will be performing 
       CRUD operations only, you don't need to add anything*/
    }

You will then have a controller where you will perform your crud operations

@RestController
public class Controller {
  @Autowired
  PersonRepository personRepo;

  @PostMapping("/save")
  public void addAppointment(Person person) {
    personRepo.save(person);
  }

  @PutMapping("/update")
  public void updateAppointment(int personID, String description, int customerID) {
      //retrieve the user whose appointment you want to update then update the relevant fields and save user;
        Person person = personRepo.findById(personID);
        person.setDescription(description);
        person.setCustomerID(customerID);
        personRepo.save(person);
      }

  
}
```

You can read up more on this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-how-to-access-database-using-spring-data-jpa/)